# how can i get my wordpress post content to appear in the facebook like broadcast on facebook?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-like

I have the "Really simple Facebook and Twitter share buttons" plugin installed for my wordpress page, and it is functioning fairly well in placing working facebook 'like' buttons on each posting I have. The 'likes' are going through to facebook appropriately.

However, the 'like' broadcast that appears in peoples' timelines after they like each posting does not display any content from the wordpress post (title, picture, body text). The broadcast is empty except for the name of my blog ("treatings") and the url right under (treatin.gs).

I don't think this is an issue that can be fixed with facebook's Open Graph, although I might be wrong. I have a feeling it is a problem with the plugin (php). Any advice as to where to look to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run one of your posts through the [Facebook URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see what it has to tell you. My guess is you don't have any [open graph metadata](http://opengraphprotocol.org/) in your head.

There are many plugins that will do this for you. I haven't used your sharing plugin, but it does not look like this adds any metadata. To add the metadata, I personally think the [Yoast WordPress SEO](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) plugin is the best for this, but there are lots of other plugins out there that will add this for you.

Make sure after you add a new social plugin to run a test through the URL debugger. Lots of them add metadata to your site. Having too much metadata can be just as bad as having none.

Answer (score 0):

Once you’ve got your blog up and running, you might want to broadcast your website posts to your [social networks](https://www.infotainmentblog.com/) like Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn to gain visibility and page views. It’s a great way to reach out to a different audience who prefers social networking vs. receiving an e-newsletter, and enables you to share your posts through “retweets” or “Likes” thereby increasing your web popularity for SEO (Search Engine Optimization) purposes.

The first thing you should understand is the difference between installing an app through the social media platform or installing a plugin through WordPress. Apps tend to be more reliable than WordPress plugins for this particular purpose because as Facebook/Twitter change their systems over time, WordPress plugins often become outdated, break, or the vendor no longer keeps them up-to-date. In other words, if you use an app implemented through Facebook/Twitter, those platforms will keep themselves up-to-date without having to upgrade anything yourself within WordPress